# Criar mais um campo no input com a tecla enter

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou trabalhando em um formulário em HTML para receber os dados de um leitor de código de barra.

Seguinte: cada vez que o leitor carregar no `input` o valor do código de barra ele  automaticamente dar um enter que é o `event.keyCode= 13` então... eu preciso que alem de ele criar o próximo campo (`input`) ele pule ja para o próximo `input` e assim sucessivamente que ele já fica no aguardo dentro do proximo campo esperando o valor.

(atualmente estou clicando na tecla TAB para poder pular para o próximo campo queira fazer isso automaticamente )

Alguém pode me ajudar a ajustar o código abaixo manjo pouco de javascript e jquery

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://demos.codexworld.com/includes/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="http://demos.codexworld.com/includes/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var maxField = 10; //Input fields increment limitation
    var addButton = $('.add_button'); //Add button selector
    var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); //Input field wrapper
    var fieldHTML = '<div><input id="campo" type="text" name="field_name[]" value=""/><a  href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button">-</a></div>'; //New input field html 
    var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1
    
    //Once add button is clicked
    $(addButton).click(function(){
        //Check maximum number of input fields
        if(x < maxField){ 
            x++; //Increment field counter
            $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); //Add field html
        }
    });
    
    //Once remove button is clicked
    $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove(); //Remove field html
        x--; //Decrement field counter
    });
});
</script>




<script>

                                
$(window).load(function(){
// aqui verifica se deu enter e clica no butao para adicionar mais um campo
 $("#campo").keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        $("#butao").click();    
    }
});
    
    
// aqui parar o submit  com o enter
$('form input').on('keypress', function(e) {
    return e.which !== 13;
});


    });
                                

</script>





<form name="codexworld_frm" action="" method="post">
                <div class="field_wrapper">
                  <div>
                        <input id="campo" type="text" name="field_name[]" value=""/>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field" id="butao"><span class="glyphicon-class">+</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>
                </form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Olá @kibarco-net, tudo bom?

Tenta utilizar o focus() do JQuery. Ele faz com que o cursor esteja posicionado exatamente no campo que você deseja.

Dá uma olhada nesse link: https://www.linhadecomando.com/javascript/javascript-setando-o-foco-em-um-campo.

Answer (score -1):

Basta utilizar a função `$(element).focus()` 
Segue Exemplo

```js
    function fTeste() {
        $('#i3').focus()
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <input id="i1" type="text">
        <input id="i2" type="text">
        <input id="i3" type="text">
        <input type="button" onclick="fTeste()" value="input 3">
```

Answer (score -1):

Acho que entendi o que você quer fazer... eu fiz assim :

// Quando tecla enter é acionada

```
$(document).keypress(function(event){
            var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
            if(keycode == '13'){
                if(x < maxField){ 
                    x++; //Incrementa contador do campo
                    $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); //Add field html
                    $('input[type=text]:last')[0].focus();
                }
            }
        });
```

// Uma vez que o botão Adicionar é clicado

```
$(addButton).click(function(){
    //Check maximum number of input fields
    if(x < maxField){ 
        x++; //Incrementa contador do campo
        $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); //Add field html
        $('input[type=text]:last')[0].focus();
    }
});
```